# How to Merge Data to Dynamics 365 Sales from Databricks on Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, dynamics-365-sales

The following will allow me to Append data to the table Account in Dynamics 365 Sales:

```
driver = "cdata.jdbc.dynamicscrm.DynamicsCRMDriver"
url = "jdbc:dynamicscrm:RTK=524D.....;User=Username;Password=Password;URL=https://org.crm11.dynamics.com/;CRM Version=CRM Online;"

df.write.mode("append") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", 'Account')\
    .save()
```

I am applying the code using pyspark in Databricks on Apache Spark

Can someone show me how to merge to the table Account?

Comment: hi @Patterson, please follow this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6ea2x9WdaU, it will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for video. However, the video just shows how to Append, but I need to know how to Merge